# What happened to yesterday's reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday I gained 25 reputation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587307/windows-form-recieve-text-input/43587695#43587695) (also posted on yesterday) and 2 reputation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15931388) edit. Then today when I logged on I saw I had gained no reputation.

I looked in my history and it said no net reputation gain, of course I know that means if I lost the same amount it would say that. However I can see no direct cause and `stackoverflow.com/reputation` tells me: `-- 2017-04-25 rep 0 = 1571`.

So what I'm really asking is: How can I see what answer I lost my reputation on?

*Notes* *

- I checked my recently deleted answers and I had 2 deleted answers from yesterday but they had no `+1`'s.
- I did not contribute to the documentation

**After some digging:**
After looking around I found 1 of my deleted answers, but this one was not accepted and had +2 and -1, this would mean I lost 18 reputation there but that leaves 9 reputation still not accounted for.

Comment: Have you looked at your recently deleted posts? See anything at `http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/2885376` or `http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/2885376`

Comment: @MartinSmith Yesterday's deleted answers had no +1's, good thinking though! hadn't looked there yet

Comment: @MartinSmith the links don't don't work btw :)

Comment: Don't know why. I took the link that works for me and substituted your userid in.

Comment: @MartinSmith If I open it myself I can see the link is 100% the same but if I copy paste it, it won't work -_-

Comment: Did you contribute to SO Documentation? IIRC deleted Documentation entries don't show up in the rep overview.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Nope did not contribute, good thinking I'll add it so answerer's know :)

Comment: How much less? Perhaps a post you edited was deleted.

Comment: @RobertLongson I posted that answer yesterday and it tells me no net reputation gain so at least 25 *edit* exactly 25

Comment: Scratch that, got 2 from an edit too so 27

Comment: @EpicKip I see -9 for yesterday comprising a +10, -2 and -18 although that's a little confusing. The most rep you've had is 1591 and since you're now at 1571 -   that's a difference of 20 - so the real net effect is that your received upvotes/downvote and approved suggested edit to the question that was deleted were  effectively annulled. (You no longer have the -2 for the downvote, the +2 from suggested edits (those cancel out) and it's like the 2 upvotes didn't happen which is a net of 0)

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for clearing that up Jon, is there any way I could get insight on this myself and not have to dig through my answers?

Comment: @EpicKip not really... It's a case of finding the post that caused it (as you did with show recently deleted?) and then doing some maths :-)

Comment: @JonClements The posts deleted by other people don't show up there though, but if you post this as answer ill accept it. Because you found the cause :)